# Share vbulletin login?

Tags: single-sign-on, vbulletin

I've had a vbulletin forum with lots of users already, and will develop another app.

I just want my new app to use existing vbulletin login. It will check if a user has logged into vbulletin, if not, send him to vbulletin login page, otherwise, let him go further to use the new app showing his vbulletin username somewhere. It looks quite simple. But I have no clue to begin, any one could help me a little bit? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all include the vBulletin global.php file in your application, then you get access to all of vB's database classes, security, user profiles, templates and so on.

Assuming your application is in the forum root directory (otherwise, you'll need to adjust paths), just add:

```
require_once('./global.php');
```

then you can do:

```
if ($vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] == 0) 
{
  // user is a guest
}
else
{
  // user is logged in
}
```

Answer (score 0):

start from including the global.php - as much as I know - this file will help you to access vbulletin sessions by using the array userinfo, something like this:

```
$vbulletin->userinfo['userid']; // this will give you 0 if the user is a guest
```